# I want to download all the snippets I have in the chrome dev tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have a large number of snippets, and want to download all of them at once. I noticed that you can download one at a time, but I have too many to do all of them quickly.

Answer (score 3):

#### Use devtools-on-devtools:

1. open **devtools** and switch its `Dock side` in the menu to a detached (floating) window

   [image]
2. in the now detached devtools press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> on MacOS,
   which will open **devtools-on-devtools** in a new window
3. in devtools-on-devtools switch to console, paste and run this code:

   ```js
   (Host.InspectorFrontendHost || InspectorFrontendHost).getPreferences(async r => {
     for (const {name, content} of JSON.parse(r.scriptSnippets || '[]')) {
       const a = document.createElement('a');
       const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([content], {type: 'text/plain'}));
       a.href = url;
       a.download = name + '.txt';
       a.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
       console.log(name + '...');
       await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 150));
       URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
     }
   });
   ```

Comment: it's work ? i got error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getPreferences')