# Is it possible to export and import custom devices from chrome developer tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I created my own custom devices on the Chrome developer tools and I would like to export them and import them in other computers ( or the same one in future installations ) without having to re create them one by one.

Is it possible to import/export some items or the whole list?

[image]

Comment: It's inside `Preferences` file in your browser profile.

Comment: Do you mean the Json file named `Preferences` on `C:\Users\%UserName%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` . Is there any way to do it from the GUI?.

Comment: You can open devtools-on-devtools for this panel and poke the internals, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67422751).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `wOxxOm` has commented, the data is in the `Preferences` file.

A more complete explanation for importing/exporting would be the following one:

- On the source computer open a chrome tab and navigate to
  `chrome://version/` this will give you some info. Get the `Profile Path` property, that's where the preferences file is saved.
- Open the preferences file and look for the
  `"customEmulatedDeviceList"` property on this file and copy it,
  that's where all the custom devices have been stored.
- Now open the same file on the target computer ( first close the
  Chrome browser or the new settings will be overriden by the current
  opened browser ) and paste the data you just copied. ( note: you
  need to create a custom device on this target computer or the
  `"customEmulatedDeviceList"` property won't exist ).

The structure to be selected, copied and pasted is easier to locate if you first format the json file with any auto formatter.

Comment: You also have to **Quit** a Chrome before saving changes, otherwise they won't apply (will be overriden)

Comment: `customEmulatedDeviceList` only showed up for me in the `Preferences` file after adding a custom device using Chrome's dev tools (GUI).

Comment: @Sammeeey, yes, that is explained on the note on third bullet point.

Comment: @nezort11, I forgot to add that, I'll edit the third bullet point to explain that.

Comment: In **2024**, this way still works, but look for `custom-emulated-device-list` in the Preferences file.