# Is there a quick way to save unabridged console log in chrome

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

I am debugging a web application which dumps big messages in using `console.log`, the messages are quite long (easily exceeding 30K characters).
When I open devTools console, all these messages are trimmed to 5025 characters - in order to see the complete messages, I need to click 'Show more' on each one of them. If I don't do 'Show more' and just save the log, the messages will be dumped in the trimmed form as they are shown.

I wonder if there is a way to save everything that was dumped to console.log to a file without clicking on every message.

Note, I have tried running chrome with `--enable-logging --v=1` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627113/save-the-console-log-in-chrome-to-a-file), but I don't see the console messages from javascript there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write console.log to a file instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54654946/how-to-write-console-log-to-a-file-instead)

Comment: Not quite - I cannot really override or replace `console.log` - I am debugging web assembly, so it is emscripten-generated code that redirects `std::cout` to `console.log`

Comment: Ideally "Save as" command in the console context menu would do it, but it cuts the text just the same, which I consider a bug in devtools. Meanwhile the workaround would be to find some chrome extension for debugging that writes complete text. Another method is to extract the text using devtools-on-devtools, see these [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3959875+%22devtools-on-devtools%22).

Comment: @Serge Have you actually tried that? Changing `performance.now` easily hacks into WASM time calculations

Comment: copy(....code....) in console copies the output to clipboard

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment from @wOxxOm and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67421739/i-want-to-download-all-the-snippets-i-have-in-the-chrome-dev-tools/67422751#67422751) the answer is devtools on devtools:

1. In the now detached devtools press `Ctrl+Shift+i` or `⌘+Shift+i` on MacOS,which will open devtools-on-devtools in a new window
2. In the console paste the following code:

```js
    {
        let content = '';
        for(const msg of UI.panels.console.childrenInternal[0].consoleMessages)
        {
            if(msg.message.messageText.startsWith('====')) {        // filtering only the messages I need
                content += msg.message.messageText + '\n';
            }
        }
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([content], {type: 'text/plain'}));
        a.href = url;
        a.download = 'message.log';
        a.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
        console.log(name + '...');
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 150));
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }
```